# I can only ping a computer after the other computer pinged me before

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-networking, ping

I have two computers, let's call them A (192.168.0.10) and B (192.168.0.11). I want A to ping B. However, A cannot ping B unless B pings A first.

```
# computer A
$ ping 192.168.0.11
# result: Destination Host Unreachable

# computer B
$ ping 192.168.0.10
# result: works
# 64 bytes from 192.168.0.10: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=1.76 ms

# computer A (after computer B pinged A)
$ ping 192.168.0.11
# result: works
# 64 bytes from 192.168.0.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.65 ms
```

Do you have any idea what happens? Because of this behavior I cannot `ssh` the computer before B pinged for example.

This happens in my WLAN.

Comment: Is this over some sort of VPN?

Comment: It happens in my local network. No VPN configured.

Comment: Can you show the state of the ARP table on computer A, before and after the ping ? (arp -a)

Comment: @b0fh it is kind of hard to replicate. I restarted twice both computers and It works. However, I know that this problem comes from time to time and the only solution (till now) it is to ping from B to A. :/

Answer (score 1):

Your network could be configured to do so.
Read [Cannot ping over LAN until a ping is received](https://serverfault.com/questions/462803/cannot-ping-over-lan-until-a-ping-is-received) on ServerFault.

Comment: Hello! The right way to do this is suggest closing as a duplicate of the linked question. If you can't do that due to being new, maybe just leave a comment with the link?

Comment: Okay.
Thanks Bill, I will take care next time. Unlike StackOverflow, I don't have comment rights here. I think the rights should be shared across the StackExchange network.

Comment: Oh, right! I forgot that commenting rights come later. Sorry about that!